# what does the following lines of code mean in eclipse plugin.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

```
          <menu
               label="%RunMenu.label"
               path="additions"
               id="org.eclipse.ui.run">
            <separator
                  name="stepGroup">
            </separator>
            <groupMarker
                  name="stepIntoGroup">
            </groupMarker>
            <groupMarker
                  name="stepOverGroup">
            </groupMarker>
            <groupMarker
                  name="stepReturnGroup">
            </groupMarker>
            <groupMarker
                  name="emptyStepGroup">
            </groupMarker>
         </menu>
```

i want to have one more action in the Run menu of the eclipse. So i was trying to understand the plugin.xml file, in which i found these lines. So can any one explain me what does these lines mean?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This article has a good introducion [Contributing Actions to the Eclipse Workbench](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html).

See also the feature.xml in the feature folder at the same level as the plugin folder of the plugin you wan't to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like XML is part of "Run" menu for "Debug" perspective in eclipse.

This XML defines menu contributed by Debug perspective to Run menu. Action for each of these may be defined somewhere else.

For more details you can go through "[Menu and Toolba](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_menupaths.htm)r" section from eclipse help.

You can also check following links:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecplug/

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html